# How to change QTableView like list

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2, qsortfilterproxymodel

I need to change QTableView like this
[image]

I try to use QSortFilterProxyModel, but i dont find any information about that. In documentation examples write in c++, i cant understand it

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't read the language in the screenshot you provided, can you elaborate on it ? Even better is to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem, and what is the desired result.

Comment: So, you want each row of the table to be displayed as an item "group"? You either use an item widget in a QListWidget, or a custom delegate that paints the contents of each item. In both cases, sorry but this is not a tutorial website, so please do some more research on the subject and eventually provide a MRE as requested above.